# Datawarehousing with Jasperforge, what packages i really need to start with?

Tags: open-source, jasper-reports, etl, pentaho

For a big commercial online shop my company needs to start a business intelligence project.

We have done the online shop; there are probably only a couple of data sources, so the integration i think it's quite easy.

We're creating the data warehouse database, revisiting the actual database from another point of view.

I start to look around for some open-source BI framework, and I came up with Pentaho and JasperForge as possible candidates.

I've looked at Jasperforge, but i don't understand how software/packages i need to have a frontend (like the Pentaho demo); someone can help me making a short high-level briefing of the deployment of Jasper BI Suite? I don't understand if it uses mondrian, it's included or not?

Can i use JasperServer with Microsoft SQL Server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a database set up on SQL Server, you can connect to it with JasperReports using the SQL Server JDBC driver.  iReport is the graphical tool you use to design reports.

JasperServer comes bundled with MySQL and allows for more advanced report management such as scheduling.  You can connect to Mondrian using Jasper but it sounds like that would just be complicating things in your case if you don't already use Mondrian.

The easiest way for you to get started is to [download and install iReport](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=64348&package_id=263428&release_id=670915), add the [SQL server JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99b21b65-e98f-4a61-b811-19912601fdc9&displaylang=en) to the classpath (iReport -> Tools -> Options -> Classpath -> Add JAR), then set up a new data source as 'Database JDBC connection' and select the MS driver and fill in the server details.  See how you get on with that and then look into the rest of the JasperReports package and JasperServer to see if you need any of the functionality they provide.

Comment: this is a good answer.. in the meantime i've to work jasper with sql server (via jdbc and jdts connection), then i pass into pentaho for better integration with mondrian. If i catch some free time, i will edit my post to give more details. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Pentaho Business Intelligence Suite. It can run Jasper Report. [Homepage of Penatho BI Suite](http://www.pentaho.com/)